# How to run ubuntu command on specific time

Tags: ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu system and i have setuped openfire on my system but the problem is it is automatically stop and for this i have to restart it manually for this i want to set a command of restarting openfire on specific time if it will happen then it definately resolve my problem.
Below i have mention the example.

Suppose for example i want to run below command on 2p.m.so how i can i achieve this please help me i have try do this using cronjob but its not
working.
sudo service openfire restart

Please help me,
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Login to your server with terminal
2. Type `sudo -s` to become sudoer
3. Type `crontab -e` to edit your crontab
4. Add `0 14 * * * /etc/init.d/openfire restart` to restart Openfire
   everyday at 2 PM
5. Save your file
6. Recheck with `crontab -l`

   Depending on your version, you could use `/bin/systemctl` to restart service instead of /etc/init.d

Answer (score 0):

You may use [cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto), but the better way is find out why does this script stops and fix it.
If you need to restart your script each time it stops, and you can't fix it's stopping, then you may use script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while ((1))
do
  /path/to/your/script
done
```